# Change pom property just for a specific profile

Tags: linux, bash, maven, maven-3

I need to change a pom property inside a defined profile from command line.

I just need to do it for one profile and not modify the others.
Is there a plugin which I can use to do this?

Below a snippet of one of the profiles (active by default):

```
<profile>
    <id>3.7.x</id>
    <activation>
        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
    </activation>
    <properties>
        <support.version>3.7.1</support.version>
    </properties>
</profile>
```

Thanks

Comment: Your question is really clear to me. Is the support.version property already defined in the POM and you are overriding it i the 3.7.x profile? The profile is active by default, so it will always redefine it. What are you effectively looking for?

Comment: Hi, sorry for not be so clear. I'm defining this property inside the profiles. I want to replace the value by running a bash command.

Comment: so the support.version property is only defined in each and every profile of your pom and then used somewhere else in the pom (i.e. dependency version, plugin configuration), right? Then you want to override it via command line for a specific profile which you would then activate also from command line?

Answer (score 0):

Running

```
mvn clean install -Dsupport.version=your_value
```

Would effectively change the value of the `support.version` property defined in the `3.7.x` profile, active by default.

If you want to change the value of the same property in another profile, that profile should also be activated, otherwise your change would simply be ignored.

You would hence run:

```
mvn clean install -Dsupport.version=your_value -Pprofile_name
```

That would change the `support.version` value for the profile_name profile.

However, beware that activating a profile from command line will deactivate a profile active by default in your POM (`3.7.x` in your case), but not a profile active by default as part of your settings.xml (which however will be shared by all of the Maven builds on that machine).

From Maven official documentation about [profiles](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html)

> This profile will automatically be active for all builds unless another profile in the same POM is activated using one of the previously described methods. All profiles that are active by default are automatically deactivated when a profile in the POM is activated on the command line or through its activation config.